# Assertion Error when building signed APK Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio to 0.8.2 and now and I cannot build signed APK files. I get a IDE error (below). It cannot find the path for apk tool?

```
null
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.android.sdklib.BuildToolInfo.getPath(BuildToolInfo.java:244)
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.createAndAlignApk(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:380)
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.access$200(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:81)
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$1$1.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
at  com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Comment: Show us your build.gradle

Comment: @Blundell I'm not using gradle

Comment: lol you are using Gradle, by using ASide you by default & enforced use gradle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there may have been a issue with the new Android Studio Beta 0.8.2. I uninstalled and installed 0.8.0 and the issue has resolved itself.

Comment: Do you have latest build tools?